# Cloudwatch raw json to JSON extraction in python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a python script to describe all the cloudwatch alarms and extract few key info . I used boto3 to get the result but it is in raw form . How to format this to json and extract only the required ones

```
import json

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# List alarms of insufficient data through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
for response in paginator.paginate(StateValue='INSUFFICIENT_DATA'):
    print(response['MetricAlarms'])
```

Please help!

Comment: The `describe_alarms` call returns a Python dictionary. You can use `json.dumps(...)` to convert dict to JSON string.

Comment: @jellycsc Am new to this json . Can you share a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @jellycsc you can simply use `json.dumps()` to convert the returned `JSON` into a dict. But to extract the fields out of the returned response, not sure why you want to convert that into `json` and then extract the fields.

`describe_alarms` call is already returning a list of the dicts which we can simply use and extract whichever field we want,  response of `json.dumps` is a string.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import boto3
import datetime


def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# List alarms of insufficient data through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
for response in paginator.paginate(StateValue='ALARM'):
    metric_alarms = response.get('MetricAlarms')
    for metric_alarm in metric_alarms:
        print(metric_alarm.get('AlarmName'))
        # uncomment below if json objects are needed.
        # parsed_alarm_data = json.dumps(metric_alarm, default=myconverter)
        # print(type(parsed_alarm_data))
```

```sh
❯❯ python3 x.py
TargetTracking-table/mytable-AlarmLow-ab20db06-8e66-480c-9952-b9ed751c1003
TargetTracking-table/mytable2-AlarmLow-da22b0b5-987f-4d82-aa5a-0f2e83cc8abf
```

As the `datetime` object inside the metric data is not directly serializable,

> TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

So a just have to manually handle that, so an extra class , depending on your reuirement you can handle as you want.

The `json.dumps` method can accept an optional parameter called default which is expected to be a function. Every time JSON tries to convert a value it does not know how to convert it will call the function we passed to it. The function will receive the object in question, and it is expected to return the JSON representation of the object.

I didnt had any alarm in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state, so I used `ALARM` state.

Comment: Thanks .Thats solved it. How do we extract only specific JSON fields

Comment: @JoeJ if you just want to extract fields out of the received response from `describe_alarms` API call you dont need to parse the data. I updated the answer. If you actually want to parse the data into JSON, you can uncomment the call to `json.dumps`. The response from `json.dumps` is a string and in python we can simply operate on the dicts which we are already getting out of the call.

Comment: You can add `default=str` on the `json.dumps()` call to deal with the annoying datetime objects.  I will convert them to something that can be represented in a JSON document.